# Guess a probability distribution function that take latest or more recent values from data

Tags: probability, distributions, categorical-data

Is there any good source or link that has several probability distribution functions (pdf) we can use based on the simple observations or patterns we observe from data.

The question I have in my mind is to adopt some distribution function of prospective customers of car sales based on the quotations one enter from car-dealer website (a car sale is dependent on several features eg:  Car Type -sedan or SUV, Engine kind, fully loaded etc). If I hypothesize there is more likely chance that customer with latest quotation (or recent quotation) to buy the car with the last entered set of features. Is there any pdf that can describe the population behavior?

Comment: Do you have data or just this question of interest? If you have data then you can try fitting it to probability distributions. I am familiar with what this package is in R ("fitdistrplus") although I don't know what you use, either. It's probably not terribly sexy or exciting but wikipedia usually has the PDFs for probability distributions, and it's a simple matter to find lists of common probability distributions (like Vose's Compendium of Distributions pdf online)

Comment: I do have data and I observe that latest quotation from customer with set of features is more likely to go for that option (buy the car). package 'fitdistrplus' seems to be interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple question with a big answer. Strictly speaking, the PDF of the outcome (buy/don't buy) is a Bernouilli. You have one of two outcomes (buy - don't buy), and probability $p$ that a purchase is made.

The fun begins when you want to model $p$ with information about the vehicles and the quotes. A popular starting point would be a logistic regression model. Another option would be a CART tree (or the related random forest, if you have lots of data). You could also do a probit regression, if you believe that a purchase is a thresshold event: people buy when a purchase scores high with respect to a number of criteria. There are many approaches. You need to try some models on your data, and then test how they perform on additional purchase profiles.

I realize this is a rather general answer, but the question is rather general as well.

Comment: Thanks! for giving the starting point for my analysis. I am little biased towards Bayesian philosophy, any inputs in this regard is highly appreciated.